# How do i find the inverse of: $f(x) = {2^{x - 1}} - 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, logarithms, inverse-function

$f(x) = 2^{x - 1} - 3$

My approach:

Take logs to base 2:

$ = \log_2 \left( x - 1 \right) - \log_2 \left( 2^3 \right)$

$ = \log_2 \left( {x - 1} \over {2^3} \right)$

This isn't the answer in the book, which is:

$f^{-1}(x) = \log_2 (x + 3) + 1$

Comment: $= {\log _2}(x - 1) - {\log _2}{2^3}$ is wrong. It should be $= {\log _2}(2^{x - 1} - 3)$, but that doesn't do much. Try $f(x)+3 = 2^{x-1}$ instead.

Comment: @Jerry, could you explain why that is wrong so that I dont make the same mistake again, thank you.

Comment: If you take log, you need to take logs on both side of the equation. So, after taking logs, you get $\log _2f(x)= {\log _2}(2^{x - 1} - 3)$. Also, ${\log _2}(2^{x - 1} - 3) \neq {\log _2}(x - 1) - {\log _2}{2^3}$, just like $\log(5+5) \neq \log(5)+\log(5)$.

Comment: @Later, please stop editing large numbers of old questions, as it bumps newer questions off the front page. Please edit two or three a day, not a dozen over the course of a few minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn’t take logs to base $2$: it isn’t true that $\log_2(u-v)=\log_2 u-\log_2v$, and it isn’t true that $\log_22^{x-1}=\log_2(x-1)$. Moreover, taking the log base $2$ of $y=2^{x-1}-3$ doesn’t solve for $x$, which is what you need to do in order to find the inverse function.

What you want to do is solve $y=2^{x-1}-3$ for $x$. Add $3$ to both sides: $y+3=2^{x-1}$. **Now** take logs base $2$ to get $x-1$ out of the exponent: $\log_2(y+3)=\log_2 2^{x-1}=x-1$. Finally, add $1$ to both sides, and you have $x$: $x=1+\log_2(y+3)$. This tells you that $f^{-1}(y)=1+\log_2(y+3)$. You’re probably expected to express $f^{-1}$ with $x$ as the independent variable instead of $y$, so just replace $y$ everywhere that it occurs with $x$: $f^{-1}(x)=1+\log_2(x+3)$.

Comment: Just before you take $\log_2$, if you're really careful, you note that the equation is impossible unless $y > -3$, and then you're sure you don't tak log on a negative quantity. This also tells what the domain of $f^{-1}$ is, which some people would like to be a part of the full solution.

Comment: @Jeppe: Or you can wait until you’re done with the manipulations and then sort out the domain.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the classic "switch $x$ and $y$ approach."

$$x=2^{y-1}-3\\x+3=2^{y-1}\\y-1=\log_2(x+3)\\y=\log_2(x+3)+1$$ Alternately, if you'd prefer to avoid $y$: $$x=f\bigl(f^{-1}(x)\bigr)\\x=2^{f^{-1}(x)-1}-3\\x+3=2^{f^{-1}(x)-1}\\f^{-1}(x)-1=\log_2(x+3)\\f^{-1}(x)=\log_2(x+3)+1$$

---

You seem shaky with your log rules, so it might be better to avoid arithmetic manipulations altogether, here.

We can think of $f(x)$ as the graph of the function $x\mapsto 2^x$ shifted right by $1$ and down by $3$. We know how to invert $x\mapsto 2^x$--that's just $x\mapsto\log_2(x),$ but how do the shifts change things? To obtain the graph of an inverse function, we simply reflect the original function's graph over the line $y=x$. Hence, when we shifted to the right by $1$, our inverse shifted up by $1$, and when we shifted down by $3$, our inverse shifted left by $3$. Indeed, $f^{-1}(x)=\log_2(x+3)+1$ is simply the graph of $x\mapsto\log_2(x)$ shifted left by $3$ and up by $1$, as desired.

Answer (score 4):

Your defining equation for the function is  $y = 2^{x-1} - 3 .$  This is no general rule for the logarithm of a difference of terms, so you must move the '3' first.  You then have
$y + 3  = 2^{x-1}$ .  You can now use logarithms from this point.  Once you have solved for $x$  , you can swap variables to write your expression as an inverse function on  $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the inverse of a function can be done by re-arranging to make $x$ the subject of the equation:

$$f(x)=2^{x-1}-3\implies2^{x-1}=f(x)+3 \implies x=\log_{2}\left(f(x)+3\right)+1$$

We now rename $x$ to $f^{-1}(x)$ and $f(x)$ to $x$ to get our inverse function:

$$f^{-1}:x\mapsto \log_{2}(x+3)+1 \quad\text{or}\quad f^{-1}(x)=\log_{2}(x+3)+1$$

As required.